# Ajax, when response has some value i want to treat it as an ajax error

Tags: jquery, ajax

Whats happening is , 
I am already working on a big application, the way that the team handles the server side errors that they send a Json response with `error=true` *(its still 200 success) (its hard for me to change that to send different status codes)*, and in the ajax success they call the same function to alert using a dialog with an error message if `error=true` else execute the normal logic,

what i want is to use a single ajax event to hook in before any success happens and check first if the value has *error=true* then don't call its success handler and show the dialog

Comment: Why don't you just test the AJAX data at the beginning of your `success` callback?

Comment: @Blazemonger Great minds... ;) http://stackoverflow.com/a/14877859/370103

Comment: that is already what i do , just asking if there is more automatic way using events

Comment: No, there's no built-in response validation in jQuery AJAX, it just looks at the HTTP response code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the structure of your `success` and `error` handlers to run the same code if `error=true`.

For example you could do:

```
$.ajax(
   success: function(data){
      if (data.error){
         RunErrorCode();
         return;
      }
      //success code...
   },
   error: function(){
      RunErrorCode();
});

function RunErrorCode(){
   alert("An error has occurred");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function to validate the response:

```
var hasErrors = function(response) {
  if(response.error) {
    //...
    return true;
  }
};
```

Then on each `success` callback, call `hasErrors`.

```
$.ajax({
  //...
  success: function(response) {
    if(hasErrors(response)) return;
    //...
  }
})
```